# Delphi 5 - size mismatch on TField

Tags: delphi, ado, field, delphi-5

On an ADOQuery I've created a String Tfield and set the it's [size](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TFieldDef.Size) to 24(from Fields Editor).

When I'm trying to assign to this field a 24 characters length string `(qry.fieldbyname('fieldname').asString`), only first 20 characters are added. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is the query populated with data? If you are doing a select against a table then the column will have the same width as in the table schema. Check how the column is defined in your database.

Comment: my mistake. copy/paste the components have strange effects sometimes in D5